# Operational definition of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass

The following sentences are from "An Introduction to Mechanics" Kleppner and Kolenkow. I couldn't really understand what the example (in italics) is trying to explain especially the sentences in bold :

> Operational definitions may be satisfying theoretically, but they can
>   be useless in practice because in principle they are limited to situations
>   in which the operations can be carried out. However, this is not usually
>   a problem; physics proceeds by constructing a chain of theory and experiment
>   that allows us to employ convenient methods of measurement
>   but that are ultimately based on the operational definitions.
>
> *For example,
>   the gravitational force on an object turns out to be proportional to its
>   mass. Because weight is proportional to mass, one can compare masses
>   simply by comparing weights.**The most practical way to find the mass
>   of a mountain, for instance, is to observe its gravitational pull on a test
>   body, such as a hanging plumb bob, essentially comparing the mass of
>   the mountain to the mass of the Earth.*** If we had to employ the operational
>   definition of mass, we would need to apply a standard force and
>   measure the mountain’s acceleration. This would be impractical, to say
>   the least. Fortunately, the two methods are directly related conceptually.

Comment: They choose a wrong example as for is also difficult to go around a mountain with a bob without the latter feeling the rest of the Earth. With a meteorite perhaps, but still impractical.  Back to the mountain, perhaps a comparison of the gravitational field there as compared to the average surrounding can give a result. But the overall meaning seems clear. Think about measuring masses on a balance.  There is no motion no acceleration. Still we know we are getting the mass.

Comment: For future people coming to this question as I did, more information can be found in the [Schiehallion experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiehallion_experiment)

Answer (score 2):

Basically what they are saying is that there is a difference between how things are theoretically defined and how you'd measure them in practice. In this concrete example, the *operational definition* of mass seems to be the one in Newton's law: $F=ma$, i.e. the inertial mass, or resistance to acceleration. Based on this definition you would measure the mass by applying a known force to an object and measuring its acceleration.

Mass is rarely measured this way (e.g. in a mass spectrometer). More commonly we just put objects on a scale and measure the gravitational force (=weight) which is proportional to the mass. This is an indirect measurement.

As for the mountain, the only practical way to measure its mass would be through its gravitational force on another object of known mass.

So no really deep meaning here. Only that in practice we have to do things differently than in theory.

To give you another example,the metre is defined as the distance that light travels in 1/299792458 seconds. However usually you don't measure distances by stopping the time that light takes to travel.